Как в windows 10 сделать редирект запроса на localhost:port?
Ресурс находится на 5000 порту на хосте.
Зашел в etc/host и сделал запись:
127.0.0.1 mysite.ru

Затем в CMD в режиме админа ввел:
ipconfig /flushdns

Если зайти в браузер по адресу https://mysite.ru то выходит стандартное сообщение:

Как вы здесь оказались?

И если вручную указать порт, например mysite.ru:5000, то тогда только открывается ресурс, который запущен на localhost:5000
Есть ли стандартные средства у Windows 10, чтобы запросы шли так:
mysite:443 --> localhost:5000

UPD:
Пробовал еще так:
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=mysite.ru listenport=443 connectaddress=localhost connectport=5000


тоже не получается.
Видимо есть какой-то подводный камень...

Для теста, выкл брандмауэр, с этим proxy

@Oopss, даже при выключенном брандмауэре работает  только если явно указать порт после адреса 5000 без порта - чисто по DNS - говорит как Вы здесь оказались...

listenaddress=mysite.ru если сюда 127.0.0.1?

Ну я же запрос делаю на mysite.ru, а не на 127.0.0.1. Но ради эксперимента попробовал - не помогло

Перенаправление портов работает, ниже добавил, отличия у меня протокол http и обращался по 127.0.0.1

Хттп и хттпс путаете

@eri, получается что нельзя с https на http перередиректить? А как тогда nginx это делает? Там же в конфиге если указать listen 443 ssl и указать location, то он перенаправляет же. Может из-за того, что в конфиге NGINX идет информация о сертификатах?

у нгинкса есть тлс движок, который шифрование снимает. ставь нгинкс на локалхост и самоподписные сертификаты

Попробуйте перенаправить порты, powershell от администратора
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

Написал hello world, flask, запустил
* Serving Flask app 'hello'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 493-429-632

У меня http, по этому запустил proxy на 80 порту.
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

netsh interface portproxy show all

Прослушивать ipv4:             Подключиться к ipv4:

Адрес           Порт        Адрес           Порт
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
127.0.0.1       80          127.0.0.1       5000


Добавил в hosts 127.0.0.1 hello.local по имени тоже работает.
Все работает!

сори - не видел ответ - только что так пробовал и обновил. Не прокатило... ((

отмечу как решеный, т.к. для http работать будет, а вот для https - по ходу без NGINX не обойтись...
